# I have two external drives on a server, but I cannot assign volume letters to them using DISKPART

Tags: hard-drive, diskpart, drive-letter

I have two external drives plugged into a server, used for backups. The concern that I am trying to alleviate is that these drives keep switching volume letters on restart, or if some other storage device is plugged into the server.

Yesterday, the disks were not associated with a volume, so I restarted the server, and that fixed the problem. The drives are visible to windows, and it has a letter there, but not in DISKPART. I tried assigning a letter to the drive, but I get an error message. Please see attached screenshot.

[image]

Any ideas?